# UrlFetch failed because too much traffic is being sent to the specified URL. API Function invoked automatically

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a API request function. It gets invoked on button click. It collects data from facebook API and paste it to sheet. This all happens on button click listener.

Today, in my execution log I saw that api request function is getting invoked automatically. The only possible explanation, I can think of is that yesterday, I deployed time based triggers for my API request function to run after every 5 minutes, since then I am facing this issue. However, I deleted the time based trigger but I am facing the same issue.

Then I used this function to delete all the triggers:

```
function deleteTrigger() {
  
  // Loop over all triggers and delete them
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
  }
}
```

But the function is still invoking itslef. Never happened before.

Comment: What makes you think it is still getting invoked? You checked the `Executions` tab? Also, have you looked at the `Triggers` tab, in order to check that you have actually deleted the triggers?

Comment: I checked the execution tab, the function is automatically running and failing. Then I placed delete trigger function and ran the delete function from the script editor. I still see time based triggers under All triggers.. It doesn't get deleted..

Comment: It could be the case that some triggers were created by another user, so they are not getting deleted (since `getProjectTriggers` only returns triggers from current user and proejct). If you filter the triggers to just the ones owned by you, can you still see those triggers?

Comment: It says owned by other users.  I just saw theese triggers are associated with the same project that i am working on. The container and the project is same. And I am the owner. Can we find which user that this trigger belong too?

Comment: If you are the owner of the project, you could check which users have edit access to this project, and ask them to remove their triggers. Would that be appropriate for you?

Comment: Yeah that's appropriate. I have done that. Problem sorted out now. Thanks for your help.